# How to conveniently install cx_Freeze for Python 3?

Tags: apt, python, software-installation, pip

I want to install [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) for Python 3. My Ubuntu 14.04 has Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. For Python 2 I could install cx_Freeze very conveniently using:

```
sudo apt install cx-freeze
```

However this only installs cx-freeze for Python 2 not for Python 3. Also the officialy cx_Freeze website does not contain installation hints. I'm not very firm in building software from scratch. I also tried `pip3` (version 1.5.5) but to no avail:

```
pip3 install cx-freeze
could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement
```

Therefore the question(s):

1. Is there a simple (one line) way to install cx_Freeze for Python 3?
2. If not, can someone guide me step by step through the most simple alternative please?

---

edit: Following the answer by Dumindu Mahawela I got the following output:

```
Selecting previously unselected package cx-freeze-python3.
(Reading database ... 163736 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cx-freeze-python3_4.3-0ubuntu0px0pre2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cx-freeze-python3 (4.3-0ubuntu0px0pre2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cx-freeze-python3:
 cx-freeze-python3 depends on libpython3.2 (>= 3.2~a4); however:
  Package libpython3.2 is not installed.
 cx-freeze-python3 depends on python3 (<< 3.3); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.4.0-0ubuntu2.
 cx-freeze-python3 depends on python3.2; however:
  Package python3.2 is not installed.
 cx-freeze-python3 depends on cx-freeze-common; however:
  Package cx-freeze-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cx-freeze-python3 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

which probably means that the linked debian package it not for recent Ubuntu versions (python3 << 3.3 required). I don't want to go back to Python 3.2 for this.

Searching even for more complex installation advices I found nothing that didn't have some problem or another. It might be that cx_Freeze is currently not very well supporting Python versions >= 3.3 on Ubuntu. If that's the case I would just move on and try something different. Thanks for all efforts to help!

Comment: `sudo pip3 install setuptools` followed by: `sudo pip3 install cx_Freeze` worked for me!? The command: `cxfreeze-quickstart` can then be used.

Comment: @danger89 Thanks. This is more or less the answer of angulared below. I will verify it with my system and then mark his answer as solution if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Download the `cx-freeze-python3_4.3-0ubuntu0px0pre2_amd64.deb` from [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~phobie/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/2690309/+listing-archive-extra).

Install that .deb file with the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i [.deb file name]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't want to install, amongst others because of Python3 version required <3.3 which it isn't here. I edited the question.

Comment: You may have got the wrong file. Are you sure you downloaded the above file?. If so use [ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) to install python3.2

Answer (score 1):

Run this exactly (or copy it into the terminal):-

```
sudo pip3 install cx_freeze
```

You mispelled the module's name. It is cx_freeze, not cx-freeze. BTW, I am having problems with this for some reason, although it used to work before. Anyways, this is going to work for you cause I am using a ported version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu MATE for RPi 2, for the interested).

Comment: ~5 years later - works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, this isn't convenient, but compiling `python3` from source code would allow you to install `cx_freeze` via `pip`. You could use something like `checkinstall` to replace your system version of `python3` for convenient uninstallation and versioning.